# Is every matrix group a topological group?

Tags: general-topology, matrices, group-theory

$GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is a topological group, by the embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and the continuity of all group operations in the metric topologies of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ or $\mathbb{R}$. Fine. 
But consider now any matrix group, for example $O(n,p;\mathbb{R})$ - the orthogonal group of $\mathbb{R}^{n+p}$ endowed with a bilinear form over reals with n times +1 and p times -1 which it leaves invariant. How is this a topological group, and more generally any matrix group?

Comment: Well matrix group is a subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ for some $n$ (I believe this is the definition... though not sure if there is a consensus about it) so it is a topological group with the induced topology. (if you work over other fields this should be generalized too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is every matrix group a topological group?

Yes. I mean, every group is a topological group with discrete topology. But in the case of matrices we can do better: the topology inherited from the underlying vector space (i.e. $K^{n^2}$ for a topological field $K$, e.g. $K=\mathbb{R}$).

> the orthogonal group of $\mathbb{R}^{n+p}$ endowed with a bilinear form (...)

That's irrelevant. What you need for a group to be a topological group is that both multiplication $G\times G\to G$ and the inverse function $G\to G$ to be continuous. As long as by "matrix group" you mean a group under standard matrix multiplication or addition then it is a topological group because it is either a subgroup of $GL_n(K)$ or $\mathbb{M}_n(K)$ respectively and it can be shown that both matrix multiplication and matrix addition are continuous (because these operations can be "built" from polynomials).

Comment: Show that $O(n,p;\mathbb{R})$ is a topological group, then

Comment: @DanielC Is it a subgroup of $GL_n$? Yes. Done.

Comment: What are the open sets then?

Comment: @DanielC Subspace topology inherited from $GL_n$ (which inherits it from $K^{n^2}$). There's nothing more to it, really.